# Building Error D8004: "/wd" with Visual Studio 2013 (CommonAPI-DBUS)

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013, build

I just tried to build my **CommonAPI-DBUS** visual studio solution that I produced with CMake. 
The build fails and gives me the Error :

> Fehler 1   error D8004: "/wd" erfordert ein Argument.  D:\Programmieren\cplusplus\commonapi\common-api-dbus-runtime\build\cl   CommonAPI-DBus

Here is the CommonAPI-DBUS.log :

```
   Der Buildvorgang wurde am 07.09.2016 09:20:59 gestartet.
     1>Projekt "D:\Programmieren\cplusplus\commonapi\common-api-dbus-runtime\build\CommonAPI-DBus.vcxproj" auf Knoten "2", Build Ziel(e).
     1>ClCompile:
         C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\bin\x86_amd64\CL.exe /c /I"D:\Programmieren\cplusplus\commonapi\common-api-dbus-runtime\include" /I"D:\Programmieren\cplusplus\commonapi\common-api-runtime\include" /I"D:\Programmieren\cplusplus\commonapi\dbus-1.10.10" /I"D:\Programmieren\cplusplus\commonapi\common-api-dbus-runtime\\\"D:\Programmieren\cplusplus\commonapi\dbus-1.10.10\cmake\build\"" /Zi /nologo /W3 /WX- /Od /Ob0 /D WIN32 /D _WINDOWS /D _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS /D COMMONAPI_INTERNAL_COMPILATION /D COMMONAPI_DLL_COMPILATION /D _DEBUG /D COMMONAPI_DBUS_VERSION_MAJOR=3 /D COMMONAPI_DBUS_VERSION_MINOR=1 /D "CMAKE_INTDIR=\"Debug\"" /D CommonAPI_DBus_EXPORTS /D _WINDLL /D _MBCS /Gm- /EHsc /RTC1 /MDd /GS /fp:precise /Zc:wchar_t /Zc:forScope /Fo"CommonAPI-DBus.dir\Debug\\" /Fd"CommonAPI-DBus.dir\Debug\vc120.pdb" /Gd /TP /wd"///;4503///" /errorReport:prompt "D:\Programmieren\cplusplus\commonapi\common-api-dbus-runtime\src\CommonAPI\DBus\DBusAddress.cpp" "D:\Programmieren\cplusplus\commonapi\common-api-dbus-runtime\src\CommonAPI\DBus\DBusAddressTranslator.cpp" "D:\Programmieren\cplusplus\commonapi\common-api-dbus-runtime\src\CommonAPI\DBus\DBusClientId.cpp" "D:\Programmieren\cplusplus\commonapi\common-api-dbus-runtime\src\CommonAPI\DBus\DBusConnection.cpp" "D:\Programmieren\cplusplus\commonapi\common-api-dbus-runtime\src\CommonAPI\DBus\DBusDaemonProxy.cpp" "D:\Programmieren\cplusplus\commonapi\common-api-dbus-runtime\src\CommonAPI\DBus\DBusError.cpp" "D:\Programmieren\cplusplus\commonapi\common-api-dbus-runtime\src\CommonAPI\DBus\DBusFactory.cpp" "D:\Programmieren\cplusplus\commonapi\common-api-dbus-runtime\src\CommonAPI\DBus\DBusFreedesktopPropertiesStub.cpp" "D:\Programmieren\cplusplus\commonapi\common-api-dbus-runtime\src\CommonAPI\DBus\DBusFunctionalHash.cpp" "D:\Programmieren\cplusplus\commonapi\common-api-dbus-runtime\src\CommonAPI\DBus\DBusInputStream.cpp" "D:\Programmieren\cplusplus\commonapi\common-api-dbus-runtime\src\CommonAPI\DBus\DBusMainLoop.cpp" "D:\Programmieren\cplusplus\commonapi\common-api-dbus-runtime\src\CommonAPI\DBus\DBusMainLoopContext.cpp" "D:\Programmieren\cplusplus\commonapi\common-api-dbus-runtime\src\CommonAPI\DBus\DBusMessage.cpp" "D:\Programmieren\cplusplus\commonapi\common-api-dbus-runtime\src\CommonAPI\DBus\DBusObjectManager.cpp" "D:\Programmieren\cplusplus\commonapi\common-api-dbus-runtime\src\CommonAPI\DBus\DBusObjectManagerStub.cpp" "D:\Programmieren\cplusplus\commonapi\common-api-dbus-runtime\src\CommonAPI\DBus\DBusOutputStream.cpp" "D:\Programmieren\cplusplus\commonapi\common-api-dbus-runtime\src\CommonAPI\DBus\DBusProxy.cpp" "D:\Programmieren\cplusplus\commonapi\common-api-dbus-runtime\src\CommonAPI\DBus\DBusProxyBase.cpp" "D:\Programmieren\cplusplus\commonapi\common-api-dbus-runtime\src\CommonAPI\DBus\DBusProxyManager.cpp" "D:\Programmieren\cplusplus\commonapi\common-api-dbus-runtime\src\CommonAPI\DBus\DBusServiceRegistry.cpp" "D:\Programmieren\cplusplus\commonapi\common-api-dbus-runtime\src\CommonAPI\DBus\DBusStubAdapter.cpp" "D:\Programmieren\cplusplus\commonapi\common-api-dbus-runtime\src\pugixml\pugixml.cpp" "D:\Programmieren\cplusplus\commonapi\common-api-dbus-runtime\src\murmurhash\MurmurHash3.cpp"
     1>cl : Befehlszeile error D8004: "/wd" erfordert ein Argument.
     1>Die Erstellung des Projekts "D:\Programmieren\cplusplus\commonapi\common-api-dbus-runtime\build\CommonAPI-DBus.vcxproj" ist abgeschlossen, Build Ziel(e) -- FEHLER.

Fehler beim Buildvorgang.

Verstrichene Zeit 00:00:00.35
```

To translate for you it says: Commandline error D8004 : "/wd" needs an Argument. I don't have a deeper knowledge of the CommonAPI-DBUS project. I'm just trying to build it so that I can use it for my Some/IP project.

Where do I have to look to solve or find this error in my project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just solved my problem which I produced by myself. 
In my CMakeLists.txt was this code:

```
if (MSVC)
# Visual C++ is not always sure whether he is really C++
set(CMAKE_C_FLAGS "${CMAKE_C_FLAGS} -D_CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS -           
DCOMMONAPI_INTERNAL_COMPILATION -DCOMMONAPI_DLL_COMPILATION /EHsc   
/wd\\\"4503\\\"")
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -D_CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS -
DCOMMONAPI_INTERNAL_COMPILATION -DCOMMONAPI_DLL_COMPILATION 
/wd\\\"4503\\\"")
```

In the last to line is the code

```
/wd\\\"4503"\\\
```

I accidently changed the \ to / and produced this error by myself. So the commandline could not recognize the command.